# How to combine results from multiple tables with different columns in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following 2 tables: `title` and `photo`. I want to return rows from both of these tables that are part of the same group, ordered by timestamp, and grouped into a JSON array.

Example:

```
groupId | allitems
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    | [{title1}, {photo1}, {photo2}, {photo3}, {title2}, {photo4}, ...}]
```

##### We need the following tables:

title table

```
titleId |     createdDate     | groupId |       text      | ...
---------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 2022-10-01 09:00:00 |    1    | EXAMPLE TITLE 1 | ...
2       | 2022-10-02 08:00:00 |    1    | EXAMPLE TITLE 2 | ...
3       | 2022-10-03 04:00:00 |    2    | EXAMPLE TITLE 3 | ...
```

photo table

```
photoId |      timestamp      | groupId |     url       | ...
-------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 2022-10-01 10:00:00 |    1    | http://www... | ...
2       | 2022-10-02 03:00:00 |    1    | http://www... | ...
3       | 2022-10-02 11:00:00 |    1    | http://www... | ...
4       | 2022-10-04 01:00:00 |    2    | http://www... | ...
5       | 2022-10-04 05:00:00 |    2    | http://www... | ...
6       | 2022-10-04 06:00:00 |    2    | http://www... | ...
```

##### Result

```
groupId | allitems
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    | [{titleId: 1, createdDate: "2022-10-01 09:00:00", groupId: 1, text: "EXAMPLE TITLE 1", ...}, 
        |  {photoId: 1, timestamp: "2022-10-01 10:00:00", groupId: 1, url: "http://www...", ...}, 
        |  {photoId: 2, timestamp: "2022-10-02 03:00:00", groupId: 1, url: "http://www...", ...},
        |  {titleId: 2, createdDate: "2022-10-02 08:00:00", groupId: 1, text: "EXAMPLE TITLE 2", ...}
        |  {photoId: 3, timestamp: "2022-10-02 08:00:00", groupId: 1, url: "http://www...", ...}]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2    | [{titleId: 3, createdDate: "2022-10-03 04:00:00", groupId: 2, text: "EXAMPLE TITLE 3", ...},
        |  {photoId: 4, timestamp: "2022-10-04 01:00:00", groupId: 2, url: "http://www...", ...},
        |  {photoId: 5, timestamp: "2022-10-04 05:00:00", groupId: 2, url: "http://www...", ...},
        |  {photoId: 6, timestamp: "2022-10-04 06:00:00", groupId: 2, url: "http://www...", ...}]
```

Each row contains the groupId and all the titles + photos ordered by timestamp, that are in the form of an JSON array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have built your json objects using `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT`, you can use `JSON_AGG` to aggregate on your "*groupId*" value.

You take out both "*tab1.createdDate*" and "*tab2.timestamp*" to take care of the order of your elements inside the array, during the aggregation, using an `ORDER BY` clause.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT groupId,
           createdDate AS date_,
           JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('titleId'    , titleId,
                             'createdDate', createdDate,
                             'groupId'    , groupId,
                             'text'       , text_)    AS json_obj
    FROM tab1

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT groupId,
           timestamp_,
           JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('photoId'  , photoId,
                             'timestamp', timestamp_,
                             'groupId'  , groupId,
                             'url'      , url)       AS json_obj
    FROM tab2
)
SELECT groupId, 
       JSON_AGG(json_obj ORDER BY date_) AS all_items
FROM cte
GROUP BY groupId
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hQqPrxbcPfJLUsaziZYsnQ/1).

Comment: Appreciate the quick response @lemon! This query works off the assumption that there will only be 1 title in a group, but I just updated the example tables to where now the result has multiple titles for group 1. 
Is there a way to update this query to sort the combined rows by timestamp / createdDate?

Comment: The idea is to use "*tab1.createdDate*" and "*tab2.timestamp*" before the aggregation to give an order to the elements during the aggregation. We can do it as long as `JSON_AGG` gives the possibility of a row ordering. Got both the answer and the link at the bottom of the answer updated accordingly.